# Open Skype for business (chat window) from Xamarin Forms portable

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This supposed to be a simple task, but whatever I try the following code opens Skype for business app, not the chat window:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("sip:SkypeEmailForBusiness@mycompany.com"));
```

I need to open the chat window of that contact,

Note that I'm already logged in and I have that person added to my list. Also I'm doing this on Android device (i've tried on two different devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-uris/sfbmobileuri

Its weird that most answers I found doesnt mention this one. but basically you will need to use this format:
URI Examples

Start a chat:

```
"ms-sfb://chat?url=user%40contoso.com"

"ms-sfb://chat?id=user@contoso.com"
```

Start a call:

```
"ms-sfb://call?id=+1425-555-1234"

"ms-sfb://call?id=user@contoso.com"
```

Start a video call (Android only):

```
"ms-sfb://call?id=user@contoso.com&video=true"
```